# file upload not working while ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

see below code ,inserting and updating all are working fine but  i can't get success message,i am getting like this error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
```

how to remove the error and how to get success message

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#user-submit").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if($("form#newUserForm").valid()){
  var formData = new FormData();
  var formData = new FormData($('#newUserForm')[0]);
  formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
 $.ajax({
 url: 'horoscope-check.php',
 type: 'POST',
 data: formData,
 async: false,
 cache: false,
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
 success: function (data) {
  var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
  console.log(res);
 },
 
});

  return false;
  }else{
 console.log("false");
  }
});
  });
</script>


<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
 $ssmid = "SSM84175";
 $filename  = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
 $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $new_name= md5($filename.time()).'.'.$extension;
 $approved = 0;
 $approved_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $updated_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $status = 0;
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "horoscope/".$new_name)) {
 // FILE TYPE CHECKING
  $allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
 if(!in_array($extension,$allowed) ) {
  $horoscope = array("message" => "filetype error");
  echo json_encode($horoscope);
 }
 else{
 if($_FILES['file']['size']>2459681){
  $horoscope = array("message" => "filesize error");
  echo json_encode($horoscope);
 }
 else{
  //echo "filesize(success)";
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_horoscope WHERE ssm_id='$ssmid'");
  $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
  if($count != 0){
   $horoscope = array("Count" => $count);
   $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE user_horoscope SET horoscope='$new_name',updated_on='$updated_on' WHERE ssm_id='$ssmid'");
   if($sql){
   $horoscope = array("message" => "update success");
   }else{
   $horoscope = array("message" => "update error");
   }
   echo json_encode($horoscope);
  }else{
   //$horoscope = array("message" => 'error');
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_horoscope (ssm_id,horoscope,approved,approved_on,status) VALUES ('$ssmid','$new_name','$approved','$approved_on','$status')");
   if($sql){
   $horoscope = array("message" => "successully insert");
   }else{
   $horoscope = array("message" => "insert error");
   }
   echo json_encode($horoscope);
  }
  echo json_encode($horoscope);
 } 
 } 
}else{
 //echo "Error";
 $horoscope = array("message" => "file is not moving");
 echo json_encode($horoscope);
} 
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Horoscope</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../horoscope/bootstrap.min.css">
     
     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../horoscope/_all-skins.min.css">

    <!-- Admin Extension CSS -->
    <link href="http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto-admin/edge/assets/stylesheets/theme-admin-extension.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Admin Extension Skin CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto-admin/edge/assets/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
    <link href="http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto-admin/edge/assets/stylesheets/skins/extension.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Admin Extension Specific Page Vendor CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto-admin/edge/assets/vendor/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.min.css" />

  </head>
<body>
       <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" method="POST" id="newUserForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Photo Upload</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
            <div class="input-append">
            <div class="uneditable-input">
            <i class="fa fa-file fileupload-exists"></i>
            <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
            <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
             <input type="file" id="file" name="file" value="" aria-required="true" required="" data-msg-required="Please select your file">
            </span>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
              <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="user-submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
            <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
    <script src="../horoscope/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script>-->
  <script src="http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto-admin/edge/assets/vendor/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Admin Extension Specific Page Vendor -->
  <script src="http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto-admin/edge/assets/vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 
  <script src="../horoscope/jquery.validation.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As the error says, the data you're receiving from the AJAX request is malformed. We need to see either the data you're receiving or the `horoscope-check.php` source code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code calls `echo json_encode($horoscope);` twice.

```
...
else{
        //echo "filesize(success)";
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_horoscope WHERE ssm_id='$ssmid'");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        if($count != 0){
            $horoscope = array("Count" => $count);
            $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE user_horoscope SET horoscope='$new_name',updated_on='$updated_on' WHERE ssm_id='$ssmid'");
            if($sql){
            $horoscope = array("message" => "update success");
            }else{
            $horoscope = array("message" => "update error");
            }
            echo json_encode($horoscope);
        }else{
            //$horoscope = array("message" => 'error');
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_horoscope (ssm_id,horoscope,approved,approved_on,status) VALUES ('$ssmid','$new_name','$approved','$approved_on','$status')");
            if($sql){
            $horoscope = array("message" => "successully insert");
            }else{
            $horoscope = array("message" => "insert error");
            }
            echo json_encode($horoscope);
        }
        // the next line should be commented out.
        // echo json_encode($horoscope);
    } 
...
```

See if this solves the problem.

Comment: comment that line means error gone but,success message i  cann't getting like this [object Object]

Comment: That's because `res` is an object, not the message itself. Try this: `console.log(res.message);`